# Notion of $G$-stable subsets in Moerdijk and Mrčun's Introduction to foliations and Lie groupoids

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, group-actions, diffeomorphism, orbifolds

This question is related to this [this older question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229247/g-finite-subgroup-of-operatornamediffm-the-open-g-stable-subsets-of)

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $G$ be a group of diffeomorphisms of $M$. In page 35 of [Introduction to Lie foliations and Lie groupoids](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-foliations-and-lie-groupoids/75BBFED277FF39A56594731202789016), Moerdijk and Mrčun call an $S\subset M$ a $G$*-stable* subset of $M$ when it is connected and given $g\in G$, either $S\cap gS=S$ or $S\cap gS=\emptyset$. Just after the definition, they point out that the $G$-stable subsets of $M$ are precisely the components of $G$-invariant subsets of $M$.

I am having a hard time to understand the implication, i.e., how a $G$-stable subset would need to be a connected component of a $G$-invariant subset of $M$. For instance, consider $M=\mathbb{C}$, $G=\mathbb{S}^1$ and $S=\{1\}$, where $G$ acts on $M$ by rotations around $0\in M$. In this case, $S$ is $G$-stable yet it is not a connected component of its group-action closure, $gS=G$.

In this context, don't we have to modify a little the definition of $G$-stable subsets only to include open subsets of $M$ or restrict it to finite subgroups of diffeomorphisms of $M$?